# My dataset doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, dataset

My problem is that when it gets updated it adds the previous data which was in it Again and again

and i use a *telerik grid view*

here my code in  3 layers

first one

```
    private void btnSbmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            _MyName.Add((string)row.Cells[1].Value);
        }

        foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {   // 0 - first column
            _MyAmount.Add((int)row.Cells[2].Value);
        }

        foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            _MyPrice.Add((decimal)row.Cells[3].Value);
        }

        Ref_View_Model = new View_model._View_Model();
        Ref_View_Model.GetInsertProduct(_myName, _myAmount, _myPrice, txtDt.Text);
        radGridView1.CurrentRow.Delete();
        productTableAdapter.Update(sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet);
        productTableAdapter.Fill(sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet.Product);
        MessageBox.Show("Product(s) were added", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK);}
```

second one

```
        public void GetInsertProduct( List<string> _name, List<int> _amount, List<decimal> _price, string _date)
    {
        Ref_Model = new Model._Model();
        Ref_Model.InsertProduct( _name, _amount, _price, _date);
    }
```

and the Third one

```
     public void InsertProduct(List<string> _myName, 
                      List<int> _myAmount, 
                      List<decimal> _myPrice, string _date)
```

{
    Connection_String = myconnection string

```
Query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.product(Name, Amount, Price, [date]) 
                             VALUES(@Name, @Amount, @Price, @Date);";

using ( Con = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
using ( Cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con))
{

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
   // Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_date);

    Cmd.Connection = Con;
    Con.Open();

    int recordsToAdd = _myName.Count();
    for(int x = 0; x < recordsToAdd; x++)
    {
        Cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = _myName[x];
        Cmd.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = _myAmount[x];
        Cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = _myPrice[x];
        Cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = _date;
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using global variables to keep the values that you read from the grid. If you don't clear them after the first insert, you have still the values in the global lists and you add them again to the datatable

Of course you can use just one loop to reload the global variables with the actual values present in the grid

```
private void btnSbmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This removes whatever is in the lists 
    _MyName.Clear();
    _MyAmount.Clear();
    _MyPrice.Clear();       

    // and now start adding items from scratch
    foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
    {
        _MyName.Add((string)row.Cells[1].Value);
        _MyAmount.Add((int)row.Cells[2].Value);
        _MyPrice.Add((decimal)row.Cells[3].Value);
    }
    ....
```